# Maximum Xor subset in a binary tree

Tags: algorithm

Given a tree find the maximal subset XOR of any path from root to leaf. (i.e. the subset XOR may or may not include all elements from root to leaf. So, two siblings or cousins can't belong to the same subset).

Comment: stackoverflow is not a free problem solver. Please show some effort, ask a question and state what you have tried so far.

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: I could not come up with anything! This was asked in Amazon interview to a friend. I don't understand how to approach the question, since XOR, unlike sum, can't be defined to increase or decrease under specific condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is that first consider this problem: **maximum xor subset**, as defined below:

Given a set of integers S = { a1, a2, a3, ... a|S| }, we define a function X on S as follows:
`X(S) = a1 ^ a2 ^ a3 ^ ... ^ a|S|`. (^ stands for bitwise 'XOR' or 'exclusive or')

Given a set of N integers, compute the maximum of the X-function over all the subsets of the given starting set.

Suppose the above problem can be solved in T(N), then at least your problem can be solved in O(N * T(h)). (N is number of leafs in your binary tree, and h is the height of your tree.) Probably you can make it even better, after you understand the *maximum xor subset* problem.

According to my research, **Gaussian elimination** can be used to tackle the *maximum xor subset* problem. You may refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48682/maximization-with-xor-operator.

Good luck!